# Can't get uploaded file from react js to express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload

I want to upload the file from front end developed in **React** and get that uploaded file inside **Express** js.

Below is the code snippet of React side when I am uploading the file :

```
handleUploadFile(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    var a6 = "File";
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);
    data.append('fileName', a6); 

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/addDcuments/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {data},
        json: true,
        headers: { "Authorization": cookie.load('userToken') }
        }).then((response) => {
        response.json().then((body) => {
        this.setState({ imageURL: `http://localhost:4000/${body.file}` });
        });
    });
}
```

In above code, I have taken the form and called handleUploadFile  function on it's onSubmit event.

Now, below is my backend express js code on which I am getting the uploaded file:

```
export function uploadDocument(req, res, next) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
let imageFile = req.files.file;
var ext = path.extname(imageFile.name)

    if(imageFile.mimetype == "application/pdf" ||imageFile.mimetype == "application/octet-stream"){
        imageFile.mv('D:/React Workspace/React-videos-example/file_path/'+req.body.filename+ext, function(err) {
            if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
            }

            res.json({file: `public/${req.body.filename}.pdf`});
        });
    }

}
```

In above code, when I am trying print the `req.body`, it is returning "{}" as well as I am getting one error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined.

So, my backend function has been called, but not able to getting that uploaded file. So can anyone have any solution or any reference link for this issue?

Comment: `files` really does not exist in the `req` object. Try logging `req` first and inspect what data is in there. What you probably meant to do is `req.body.files` or something of sorts.

Comment: yes, for files I am using Formdata as mentioned in my question code snippet. In formdata I am appending 2 things and when I trying to display that values on console using data.fileName, it returns undefined output.

Comment: What do you get when you log just `req`

Comment: I am getting [object object] in req.

Comment: Do, `console.log({req})`

Answer (score 0):

When using formdata, you can't use type json in your POST, it needs to be:

contentType: 'multipart/form-data'

instead of "json: true".

Comment: I have tried it, but same error I am getting. An also values in form data is not displaying  properly at react side.